# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, formatting, tuples

I'm trying to create a formatted print, and I'm receiving this error output. I'm fairly new to python, using python3.x, so any input would be really appreciated! Thank you!!

```
avgPetal_widthS = Average(petal_widthS)
avgPetal_widthVe = Average(petal_widthVe)
avgPetal_widthVi = Average(petal_widthVi)
avgPetal_lengthS = Average(petal_lengthS)
avgPetal_lengthVe = Average(petal_lengthVe)
avgPetal_lengthVi = Average(petal_lengthVi)
avgSepal_widthS = Average(sepal_widthS)
avgSepal_widthVe = Average(sepal_widthVe)
avgSepal_widthVi = Average(sepal_widthVi)
avgSepal_lengthS = Average(sepal_lengthS)
avgSepal_lengthVe = Average(sepal_lengthVe)
avgSepal_lengthVi = Average(sepal_lengthVi)

setosa = []
versicolor = []
virginica = []

setosa.append(['Setsota',avgPetal_lengthS,avgPetal_widthS,avgSepal_lengthS,avgSepal_widthS])
versicolor.append(['Versicolor',avgPetal_lengthVe,avgPetal_widthVe,avgSepal_lengthVe,avgSepal_widthVe])
virginica.append(['Virginica',avgPetal_lengthVi,avgPetal_widthVi,avgSepal_lengthVi,avgSepal_widthVi])

avgIris = (
    ['Setsota',avgPetal_lengthS,avgPetal_widthS,avgSepal_lengthS,avgSepal_widthS], 
    ['Versicolor',avgPetal_lengthVe,avgPetal_widthVe,avgSepal_lengthVe,avgSepal_widthVe],
    ['Virginica',avgPetal_lengthVi,avgPetal_widthVi,avgSepal_lengthVi,avgSepal_widthVi])

gap = ' '*3
heading = f"{'Species:':11s}{gap}{'Petal Length':12s}{gap}{'Petal Width':11s}{gap}{'Sepal Length':12s}{gap}{'Sepal Width':11s}"
print("\n")
print("="*69)
print(heading)
print("-"*69)
print("Attributes (cm):")
for i in avgIris:
    rec = f"{avgIris[i][0]:11s}{gap}{avgIris[i][1]:12f}{gap}{avgIris[i][2]:11f}{gap}{avgIris[i][3]:12f}{gap}{avgIris[i][4]:11f}"
print(rec)
```

The error I'm receiving pertains specifically to the `rec=` part, where I'm trying to space out my tuple floats.

The error is:

```
=====================================================================
Species:      Petal Length   Petal Width   Sepal Length   Sepal Width
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Attributes (cm):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meikebuettner/hello/a5_mbuettner/a5_mbuettner2017.py", line 90, in <module>
    rec = f"{avgIris[i][0]:11s}{gap}{avgIris[i][1]:12f}{gap}{avgIris[i][2]:11f}{gap}{avgIris[i][3]:12f}{gap}{avgIris[i][4]:11f}"
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: The `i` in `for i in avgIris:` is an element of the tuple `avgIris`.Each element of the tuple is a list, so its basically incorrect to have a list as an index of a tuple, is what the error is conveying.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan ah thank you! what would be a better way of running through the tuple instead of using ```i```?

Comment: There are several corrections that can be made to this code, firstly, I'll say, setosa.append(['Setsota']) basically gives you this --> `[['Setosa']]`, basically a list of lists, which I don't think you necessarily need by just looking at the above snippet. You can simply replace that `append` by saying instead that `setosa = ['Setsota',avgPetal_lengthS,avgPetal...`

Comment: okay, so once u do the above correction for all 3 variables (setosa, versicolor and virginia), u can change your if loop to look like `for i in zip(setosa, versicolor, virginia):` and then `rec = f"{i[0]:11s}{gap}...`

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan Ooooooh!! Thank you! I'm going to try that!

Comment: just the one for loop should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the items versus the index in avgIris.  Either one works, but the items = the lists inside, and the index = a pointer to which list.  Also, normally I'd use a list instead of tuple for this.  You can use either of these replacement code snippets to get what you want for rec.  Using item is shorter so you might prefer that.

```
for i in range(len(avgIris)):
    rec = f"{avgIris[i][0]:11s}{gap}{avgIris[i][1]:12f}{gap}{avgIris[i][2]:11f}{gap}{avgIris[i][3]:12f}{gap}{avgIris[i][4]:11f}"

for item in avgIris:
    rec = f"{item[0]:11s}{gap}{item[1]:12f}{gap}{item[2]:11f}{gap}{item[3]:12f}{gap}{item[4]:11f}"
```